# How to write a Decorator for a Reagent component

Tags: clojure, decorator, clojurescript, reagent, re-frame

I have some similar reagent components, that can render a given number in certain ways:

```clj
(defn plain-number [n]
  [:h1 n])

(defn pie-chart [n]
  (render-fancy-chart n))
```

And there is some (simplified) state:

```clj
(def state (r/atom {:a 5 :b 10 :c 7}))
```

And I know how to write a component, that can access that state and use one of the components to render the state:

```clj
(def fetch-and-render-pie [k]
   (let [v (get @state k)]
     [pie-chart v]))

[fetch-and-render-pie :a] ; renders pie with 5
```

So far, so good. But that's coupled and repetitive.

### The Goal:

A **decorator** would be nice, that can fetch some state and pass it to the children. The usage would look something like this:

```clj
[fetch :a
  [pie-chart]]
```

### Possible Solution:

```clj
(defn fetch [k wrapped]
  (let [v (get @state k)]
    (conj wrapped v)))
```

This worked, but it messes with the vector of the component definition and it assumes a lot of the *wrapped* component's arguments. And it failed for chained decorators.

---

There must be a clever and robust solution out there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can't rid of assumptions about arguments of decorated component just because you pass one to it and should know how to do it the same way as with function call. But you have no need to pass vector to your decorator, just a component itself should work:

```
(defn fetch [k component]
  (let [v (get @state k)]
    [component v]))

[fetch :test pie-chart] ; ~ [pie-chart (get @state :test)]
```

For chaining you'd want to support extra args for `component`:

```
(defn fetch [k component & args]
  (let [v (get @state k)]
    (into [component v] args)))

(defn prepare [s component & args]
  (let [v (keyword s)]
    (into [component v] args)))

[prepare "test" fetch pie-chart {:colourful true}]
; ~ [pie-chart (get @state (keyword "test")) {:colourful true}]
```

This resembles HOFs and threading macros a little bit.

Comment: That looks like a very promising and elegant solution. I'll try that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

with reagent only, we could use cursor

```
(defn com-a [state]
  (fn []
    [:h1 @state]))

(defn fetch [db]
  (let [state (reagent/cursor db :k)] ; assume {:k "dd"}
    (fn []
      [com-a state])))
```

with re-frame

```
(re-frame/reg-sub
  :chart-data
  (fn [db [_ query]]
    (get-in db query)))

(defn com-a [state]
  (fn []
    [:h1 @state]))

(defn fetch [db]
  (let [state (re-frame/subscribe [:chart-data [:k]])]
    (fn []
      [com-a state])))
```